# Joomla module manager :Filtering with url parameters

Tags: joomla

Looking for a way to create links that will pre-filter the module manager to specific modules.

So far, filtering based to position is working okay for me:

```
option=com_modules&view=modules&filter_position=right
```

But I can't do the same for module type or anything else.

Does anyone one know, how could I use the various filter types of the module manager ?

#### Updating my question:

For example, which url make Module Manager to display only the Menu modules ?

I tried something like this, with no success:

```
 option=com_modules&view=modules&filter_type=mod_menu
 option=com_modules&view=modules&filter_type=menu
```

My current setup is Joomla 2.5, but it will be great to know the same for Joomla 3.x

Comment: Which Joomla version?

Comment: My current case is for Joomla 2.5, but I think it would be great if there is also the same information for Joomla 3.x in the same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it: The following are the filters for Module Manager in Joomla 2.5

filter_search, 
filter_client_id,
filter_state,
filter_position,
filter_module,
filter_access,
filter_language

So, for filtering by module type in a url, it would look like:

```
option=com_modules&view=modules&filter_module=mod_menu
```

Hope this will help someone else who is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the core module manager has that capability.

Take a look at www.nonumber.nl extension Advanced Module Manager

One of the parameters it uses to determine whether to display, include or exclude a module is to look at the URL.

So what you would do is set the module to only display when your URL criteria were met.